# Script shell to automate deployment site

Tags: bash, shell, path

I'm trying to write a script shell (Mac OS X) for deploying my Awestruct site within a launch agent.
So, I have to generate site before deploying it. The command to generate site is :
`awestruct -g`

My script is myscript.sh :

```
cd /my/site/structure/base/directory
awestruct -g
```

This script is launched by the system when an event occurs.

But the problem is it doesn't know about awestruct...

My awestruct program is a part of my ruby installation and is added to my PATH variable.

When I run the script manually, it works (because it's my user who is lauynching it)
When the system detect the event and runs the script, it results as :

```
awestruct: command not found
```

The problem is the *PATH*...

Answer (score 1):

If it works manually, then in the same prompt where it works, run command:

```
which awestruct
```

That will print the program file with full path, let's assume `/usr/local/bin/awestruct`, but use whatever it really is. Then use that in your script, for example:

```
cd /my/site/structure/base/directory
/usr/local/bin/awestruct -g
```

This assumes that there are no other environment variables, only defined for your account, which `awestruct` needs. If there are, then find out what they are, and add them to your script before running awestruct, for example with line:

```
export AWESTRUCT_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=foobar
```

(Note: When you run the script normally like any program, that will not change the parent shell environment.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the path to the executable in the PATH of the user that run the script and gets the error.

You could try something like :

```
$ su - <user_that_run_the_script>
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$(which awestruct)" >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

(For Linux users, use ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile)